# JPQL multiple level join fetches

Tags: jpa, join, jpql

JPQL how to write multiple level join fetches? For example, Order - OrderItem - Product.

```
select o from Order o left join fetch o.orderItems join fetch o.orderItems.product
```

Join fetch can not have identification variable. How to write join fetch attribute product of orderItem in the example above?